# No log ouput when using TDUnitX.CurrentRunner.Log

Tags: delphi, dunitx

I am not sure how I can output some strings into Console window using DUnitX so here is my try:

```
unit Unit1;

interface
uses
  DUnitX.TestFramework;

type
  [TestFixture]
  TMyTestObject = class(TObject)
  public
    // Sample Methods
    // Simple single Test
    // Test with TestCase Attribute to supply parameters.
    [Test]
    [TestCase('TestA','1,2,3')]
    [TestCase('TestB','3,4,7')]
    procedure Test1(AValue1, AValue2, _Result : Integer);
  end;

procedure TMyTestObject.Test1(AValue1, AValue2, _Result: Integer);
begin
  TDUnitX.CurrentRunner.Log(TLogLevel.Information, 'Information');
end;

initialization
  TDUnitX.RegisterTestFixture(TMyTestObject);
end.
```

Nothing get printed so how I should write this ?

Comment: You can use Log after you change the default parameter in the project file to:  

    logger := TDUnitXConsoleLogger.Create(False)

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to output information to the console by using `system.write()`.

Answer (score 0):

DUnitX defines a class helper on TObject with a couple of Log and Status methods in the unit DUnitX.TestFramework. Whenever this unit is in your uses list, you can call those methods on *any* object, for example in the following way:

```
uses
  DUnitX.TestFramework;

[...]

procedure TMyTestObject.Test1(AValue1, AValue2, _Result: Integer);
begin
  self.Log(TLogLevel.Information, 'Information');
end;
```

The syntax works because class helpers are a way to add methods and properties to already defined classes. By defining a class helper on TObject, *all objects* are extended.

Class helpers are described in the Embarcadero Wiki: [Class and Record Helpers (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi))

Answer (score 0):

The **quiet mode must be disabled** when TDUnitXConsoleLogger is created.

```
logger := TDUnitXConsoleLogger.Create ( False {quietMode} );
```